# CameraX TextureView issue in Android 14 Beta

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I just updated my sdk from 33 to UpsideDownCake(Android 14 beta), after update camera preview adding some additional line in preview as show in screenshot below.[image]

Tested on below marked Emulators:

[image]

Comment: Does it only happen to emulators or does it happen to real device too? This might be an emulator bug.

Comment: I don't have real device right now so i tested with emulators .